# When is dd suitable for copying data? (or, when are read() and write() partial)

Tags: io, dd

*Short version:* In what circumstances is `dd` safe to use for copying data, safe meaning that there is no risk of corruption due to a partial read or write?

*Long version — preamble:* `dd` is often used to copy data, especially from or to a device ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-can-i-use-dd-to-migrate-data-from-an-old-drive-to-a-new-drive)). It's sometimes attributed mystical properties of being able to access devices at a lower level than other tools (when in fact it's the device file that's doing the magic) — yet `dd if=/dev/sda` is the same thing as `cat /dev/sda`. `dd` is sometimes thought to be faster, but [`cat` can beat it in practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492). Nonetheless, [`dd` has unique properties that make it genuinely useful sometimes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days).

*Problem:* `dd if=foo of=bar` is not, in fact, the same as `cat <foo >bar`. On most unices¹, `dd` makes a single call to [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html). (I find [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) fuzzy on what constitutes “reading an input block” in `dd`.) If `read()` returns a partial result (which, according to POSIX and other reference documents, it's allowed to unless the implementation documentation says otherwise), a partial block is copied. Exactly the same issue exists for `write()`.

*Observations*: In practice, I've found that `dd` can cope with block devices and regular files, but that may just be that I haven't exercised it much. When it comes to pipes, it's not difficult to put `dd` at fault; for example try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782806/not-understanding-dd-command-arguments-at-all):

```
yes | dd of=out bs=1024k count=10
```

and check the size of the `out` file (it's likely to be well under 10MB).

*Question*: In what circumstances is `dd` safe to use for copying data? In other words, what conditions on the block sizes, on the implementation, on the file types, etc, can ensure that `dd` will copy all the data?

([GNU dd](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#dd-invocation) has a `fullblock` flag to tell it to call `read()` or `write()` in a loop so as to transfer a full block. So `dd iflag=fullblock` is always safe. My question is about the case when these flags (which don't exist on other implementations) are not used.)

¹ 
<sub>I've checked on OpenBSD, GNU coreutils and BusyBox.</sub>

Comment: I've never seen any Unixy system that really could read a few MiB in a single read(2)...

Comment: When using `count`, the `iflag=fullblock` is mandatory (or, alternatively, `iflag=count_bytes`). There is no `oflag=fullblock`.

Answer (score 31):

From the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/dd.html):

- If the `bs=`*`expr`* operand is specified and no conversions other than `sync`, `noerror`, or `notrunc` are requested, the data returned from each input block shall be written as a separate output block; if the `read()` returns less than a full block and the `sync` conversion is not specified, the resulting output block shall be the same size as the input block.

So this is probably what causes your confusion. Yes, because `dd` is *designed* for blocking, by default partial `read()`s will be mapped 1:1 to partial `write()`s, or else `sync`d out on tail padding NUL or space chars to `bs=` size when `conv=sync` is specified.

This means that `dd` is *safe to use for copying data (w/ no risk of corruption due to a partial read or write)* in every case but one in which it is arbitrarily limited by a `count=` argument, because otherwise `dd` will happily `write()` its output in identically sized blocks to those in which its input was `read()` until it `read()`s completely through it. And even this caveat is *only true* when `bs=` is specified or `obs=` is *not* specified, as the very next sentence in the spec states:

- If the `bs=`*`expr`* operand is not specified, or a conversion other than `sync`, `noerror`, or `notrunc` is requested, the input shall be processed and **collected into full-sized output blocks** until the end of the input is reached.

Without `ibs=` and/or `obs=` arguments this can't matter - because `ibs` and `obs` are both the same size by default. However, you **can get explicit** about input buffering by specifying *different sizes* for either and *not* specifying `bs=` *(because it takes precedence)*.

For example, if you do:

```sh
IN| dd ibs=1| OUT
```

...then a POSIX `dd` will `write()` in chunks of 512 bytes by *collecting* every singly `read()` byte into a single output block.

Otherwise, if you do...

```sh
IN| dd obs=1kx1k| OUT
```

...a POSIX `dd` will `read()` *at maximum* 512 bytes at a time, but `write()` every megabyte-sized output block *(kernel allowing and excepting possibly the last - because that's EOF)* in full by collecting input into **full-sized output blocks**.

Also from the spec, though:

- `count=n`

  - Copy only *n* input blocks.

`count=` maps to `i?bs=` blocks, and so in order to handle an arbitrary limit on `count=` portably you'll need two `dd`s. The most practical way to do it with two `dd`s is by piping the output of one into the input of another, which surely puts us in the realm of reading/writing a *special file* regardless of the original input type.

An IPC pipe means that when specifying `[io]bs=` args that, to do so safely, you must keep such values within the system's defined `PIPE_BUF` limit. POSIX states that the system kernel must only guarantee atomic `read()`s and `write()`s within the limits of `PIPE_BUF` as defined in [`limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html). POSIX guarantees that `PIPE_BUF` be *at least* ...

- `{_POSIX_PIPE_BUF}`

  - Maximum number of bytes that is guaranteed to be atomic when writing to a pipe.
  - Value: 512

...*(which also happens to be the default `dd` i/o blocksize)*, but the actual value is usually at least 4k. On an up-to-date linux system it is, by default, 64k.

So when you setup your `dd` processes you should do it on a block *factor* based on three values:

1. bs = ( obs = `PIPE_BUF` or lesser )
2. n = total desired number of bytes read
3. count = n / bs

Like:

```sh
yes | dd obs=1k | dd bs=1k count=10k of=/dev/null
10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.1143 s, 91.7 MB/s
```

You have to synchronize i/o w/ `dd` to handle non-seekable inputs. In other words, make pipe-buffers explicit and they cease to be a problem. That's what `dd` is for. The unknown quantity here is `yes`'s buffer size - but if you block that out to a *known* quantity with another `dd` then a little informed multiplication can make `dd` *safe to use for copying data (w/ no risk of corruption due to a partial read or write)* even when arbitrarily limiting input w/ `count=` w/ any arbitrary input type on any POSIX system and without missing a single byte.

Here's a snippet from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/dd.html):

- `ibs=`*`expr`*

  - Specify the input block size, in bytes, by *`expr`* *(default is 512)*.
- `obs=`*`expr`*

  - Specify the output block size, in bytes, by *`expr`* *(default is 512)*.
- `bs=`*`expr`*

  - Set both input and output block sizes to *`expr`* bytes, superseding `ibs=` and `obs=`. If no conversion other than `sync`, `noerror`, and `notrunc` is specified, each input block shall be copied to the output as a single block without aggregating short blocks.

You'll also find some of this explained better [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192092/52934).

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down in detail! So `dd ibs=1k obs=1k | dd bs=1k count=10k` is the proper way to use dd to copy exactly 10MiB?

Answer (score 8):

With sockets, pipes, or ttys, read() and write() can transfer less than the requested size, so when using dd on these, you need the fullblock flag.  With regular files and block devices however, there are only two times when they can do a short read/write: when you reach EOF, or if there is an error.  This is why older implementations of dd without the fullblock flag were safe to use for disk duplication.

Comment: Is that true of all modern unices? (I know it wasn't true of Linux at some point, possibly up to 2.0.x or 2.2.x. I rembember `mke2fs` failing silently because it called `write()` with some non-power-of-2 size (3kB IIRC) and the kernel rounded down to a power of 2.)

Comment: @Gilles that sounds like a different issue entirely.  You always have to use a multiple of the proper block size with block devices.  I am pretty sure it is true of all unicies, and it is also true for Windows.

Comment: Apart from tapes, the block size of a device is purely for the kernel to care about, or not. `cat </dev/sda >/dev/sdb` works just fine to clone a disk.

Comment: @Gilles that is because cat uses the appropriate block size, as OrbWeaver noted in his answer.

Comment: No, there is no “appropriate block size”. `cat` picks a buffer size for performance; it doesn't get any device-related information from the kernel. Apart from tapes, you can `read()` and `write()` to a block device with any size. On Linux at least, `st_blksize` depends only on the filesystem where the block device inode is located, not on the underlying device.

Comment: @Gilles my mistake.  I was thinking O_DIRECT, which does require block size and alignment.  At any rate, dd is safe to use between two block devices without the fullblock flag ;)