# How can I split a pipe into 16 byte sequences?

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm writing a bash script to automate the decryption of a certain file; however the file is encrypted in 16 byte blocks, rather than simply encoded in its entirety.

Here's some psuedo code to briefly explain why I'm trying to do:

```
cat encrypted.bin | \
buffer and output 16 bytes when asked | \
openssl --args >> decrypted.bin
```

I essentially need the pipe to open and close in order to split up the data, and am unsure of how this could be done in bash. I've looked at `split`, but since the encrypted file could be several GBs, I don't want to perform that many disk writes.

I should also point out that I'd like to know if there's a way to do this without looping through multiple pipes.

Comment: You might be able to do something clever with `split -b 16` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent-ish Linux (or any system with recent GNU coreutils), call [`split --filter`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html#split-invocation).

```
<decrypted.bin split -b 16 --filter='openssl --args "$FILE" >> decrypted.bin'
```

Independently-encrypted blocks sounds like ECB, so `openssl enc -d aes-128-ecb` may be what you're after.

If you have a strange mode that the openssl command line tool doesn't support, you may be better off using a tool that supports that strange mode. (If you describe the mode, I may be able to offer suggestions.)

You hopefully know that already, but if you aren't using a standard mode (other than ECB), your encryption is probably insecure.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the cleanest method, and doesn't use a loop.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can use instead `dd`

dd allows you to read from a file and sent the output to where you want specifying as well a blocksize.

from the man page

> DESCRIPTION
>          Copy a file, converting and formatting according to the operands.
>
> ```
>    bs=BYTES
>           read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time
> ```

So I guess that

```
dd if=encrypted.bin bs=16|openssl --args >> decrypetd.bin
```

should work for you. Although I did not tested it with openssl.

**Update** based on comment from jordamn (thanks jordamn)

The inline way does not pipe everything straith into openssl, instead pipes 16 block pieces.

```
#Get the file size in bytes
total=`ls -l encrypted.bin|awk '{print $5}'`
echo  $total;
ret=0;
i=0;
counter=0;
while [ $counter -lt $total ]
do
   #counter to know how many block we read
   counter=$(($i * 16))
   #skip is the number of block based on our setting to skip
   dd if=encrypted.bin skip=$i ibs=16 bs=16 count=1 status=none |openssl --args >> decrypit.bin
   i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: This will produce the same results as `bs=8` since all of the output will be sent to openssl in one call.

Comment: By carefull with `dd`. Don't pipe to it. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial

Comment: @EvanTeitelman but that's only a problem in regards to limiting by `count=x`, as it counts incomplete blocks.

Comment: @AlexandreAlves: looping and `dd skip` is the same I'd do (although I'm not sure about the question here). But instead of `ls | awk` you should use `stat` with %s, and instead of `str=dd skip; echo $str | openssl` you should just use `dd skip | openssl` directly. Oh and you're probably incrementing `i` wrong (if `dd` goes in steps of 16 bytes, i has to be incremented by 1 instead of 16, no?). Seriously, who encrypts anything this way?

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd written a similar script but was interested whether I could do it with a single pipe and no loop. If there is no such way however I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: @frostschutz A major game developer who didn't want modding tools developed for their game (I believe this pointless encryption method was to obfuscate).

Comment: @frostschutz you are right, I could just pipe straight from the dd instead.I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to split up and buffer the stream may be to use `xxd - make a hexdump or do the reverse` with its `-c` and `-p` options.

```
# test
n=0
printf '%s' {1..1000} | 
   xxd -p -c 16 | 
   while IFS="" read -r hexstr; do 
      n=$((n+1))
      printf '%s\n' "$n: $hexstr size: $((${#hexstr}/2)) bytes"
      printf '%s' "$hexstr" | xxd -p -r | wc -c
   done


# split up standard output stream in 16 byte blocks to be decrypted
xxd -p -c 16 encrypted.bin | 
   while IFS="" read -r hexstr; do 
      printf '%s' "$hexstr" | xxd -p -r | openssl --args >> decrypted.bin
   done
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to split a pipe into 16 byte sequences without looping through multiple pipes may be to use tools such as [cstream](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html) or [mbuffer](http://www.maier-komor.de/mbuffer.html) (in addition to the already mentioned `split -b 16` approach).

`cstream`, for example, is similar to `dd`. It not only has a `-b num` option to set the block size used for read/write, but also a `-B num` option to buffer an input block up to `num` bytes before writing. The `-n num` option limits the total amount of data to be copied to `num` bytes.