# How to acquire image of disk on Linux computer?

Tags: linux, disk, forensics

Pertaining to computer forensics, if the suspect's computer (which cannot be removed from the scene), is Linux, can you directly use tools such as *dd* or *dcfldd* on his computer to acquire the disk image? Or do you need to use forensic live cds like Helix, Penguin sleuth or FFCU on top of the existing OS?

Comment: I don't what's the right thing, but certainly you "can" use dd to obtain useful disk images (unless they're hidden or encrypted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running a command like

```
# dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/external/medium/file.img
```

on a live system will work, it's going to result in a number of problems which you won't have if you boot into a separate OS and make the image(s) from there:

1. If you image an entire disk, it probably contains a [boot loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#BOOT-LOADER) and a [partition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table). Those are going to get in your way when you go to try and do forensics/recovery on the image.

   What you really want is to image each filesystem independently:

   ```
   # dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/path/to/external/medium/filesystem1.img
   # dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/path/to/external/medium/filesystem2.img
   ...etc...
   ```

   Doing it this way makes mounting the filesystems trivial:

   ```
   # mount -oloop,ro filesystem1.img /mnt/fs1
   ```

   (I show the `mount` done as root because on some Linuxes, [loop devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) are locked down, so regular users can't use them.)
2. You're snapshotting live, mounted filesystems, so when you mount them later, it's effectively no different than if you had power-cycled the machine. The partitions will be "[dirty](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/06/14/digital-forensics-mounting-dirty-ext4-filesystems)," which can make mounting them without forensically damaging them difficult.
3. You're using the suspect machine's copy of `dd(1)`. If someone were trying to hide something from you, they could provide a sneaky or malicious copy of `dd(1)`.

Now, all that having been said, there are some *good* reasons to do an on-line clone. The best reason is that the system is using some form of filesystem or [whole-disk encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption), and rebooting it will erase the decryption keys for the mounted volumes.

`dd` is not the right tool for this job, however, since that will just get you a copy of the encrypted-at-rest data. A regular backup is a better idea. E.g.,

```
# tar -cvJf --exclude={'/proc/*','/sys/*','/tmp/*'} \
  /path/to/external/medium/everything.tar.xz /
```

That won't discover hidden partitions and such, but at least it will force the OS to decrypt every file accessible directly from the root of the filesystem.

Comment: So, the images should be stored then to an external drive of the same size, right?

Comment: If you use compression, you could possibly get away with a considerably smaller medium, since a lot of the content of the source disk will be compressible. But, I would still go into this with disk at least a little larger than the one I wanted to image. You may want to image both the whole disk and then each filesystem independently, for your own convenience, so you would need a target disk roughly twice as large as the disk you're imaging.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - indeed! And much obliged!

Comment: Beware that the live OS should not be booted on the suspect's computer. You can't trust the hardware. It may run your live OS in a VM without you noticing, to give just one simple example.

Comment: You ought to get a copy of the whole disk.  In a simple case, `kpartx` can be used to access the partitions, so #1 is not really a concern.  In a more difficult case, there might be hidden encrypted partitions and/or a modified boot system.

Answer (score 2):

In a forensic investigation, you need to retrieve data from a possibly hostile system, and you need to provide strong evidence that the data you retrieved is genuine. Acquiring a disk image from the live computer is extremely bad in both respects.

The system software may be some non-standard software that's programmed to lie to you, and provide the “interesting” data only upon presentation of credentials that you don't have. For example, you may be interacting with a virtual machine that masquerades as the real hardware. System executables or the kernel may have been modified to not report genuine data. This is both a problem for you because you want genuine data, and a problem for any legal proceedings because the suspect's lawyer will have a field day showing that you can't prove that what you grabbed was genuine.

The normal procedure for any forensics is to disconnect the storage medium and connect it to your own laptop which is running software that you can precisely account for.

Furthermore, `dd` is the wrong tool for the job because [it does not reliably copy its complete input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial). (If you're reading from a block device and not from a pipe, it might work, but good luck proving that with any measure of confidence.) At least use a proper tool like `dcfldd` or at least `cat`.

Not only can you not trust the software running on the computer, but you can't trust the hardware either. So it isn't safe to attempt to boot your own media on the suspect's computer. For example, your OS could end up running in a hypervisor that you can't detect but that returns corrupted data. You need to bring your own computer and connect the hard disk to it.

It's also important that you don't write to the suspect's computer (because you need the suspect's data, not your own data derived from the suspect's). So standard procedure is to connect the hard disk through a write blocker — a dedicated hardware component that enforces at the protocol level (e.g. USB storage protocol) that the disk will not be written to. Then you keep that grab as a reference copy — on physically write-once media if possible, on a hard disk that you never write to otherwise — and never work directly off it, only from secondary copies.

Preferably, grab an image of the whole disk, and reconstruct filesystems, etc. from there. Beware that the mere act of assembling volumes or mounting a filesystem (even read-only!) can modify it: setting a dirty bit, updating a last use date, replaying a journal, … When mounting an ext3/ext4 filesystem which wasn't cleanly unmounted, the `noload` mount option (in addition to `ro`) skips the journal update and causes nothing to be written to the disk; this has the downside that the data you'll read may be inconsistent (which can have a silver lining in making freshly deleted files still present).

If you need to get something from the live system, for example because the data is encrypted, then grab what you can the way you can. Document what you did as precisely as possible (taking videos may help). But grab the real underlying data in addition. Use what you got from the live system (typically keys) to reconstruct, in an easily traceable manner, the interesting data from the direct dump.

You'll find more information on this topic on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/), in particular:

- [Can DD on its own be used to acquire a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34310/can-dd-on-its-own-be-used-to-acquire-a-hard-drive)
- [What are the options for acquiring disk image from a Linux computer that can't be removed from a crime scene?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67041/what-are-the-options-for-acquiring-disk-image-from-a-linux-computer-that-cant-b)
- [Write-protection at hardware level for security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46684/write-protection-at-hardware-level-for-security)
- [How reliable is a write protection switch on a USB flash drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/how-reliable-is-a-write-protection-switch-on-a-usb-flash-drive)
- [What should be included in a jump bag and how often should it be reviewed?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/935/what-should-be-included-in-a-jump-bag-and-how-often-should-it-be-reviewed)

Comment: As André Daniel notes (in second linked question), a normal linux system won't write to an unmounted drive, so the write blocker seems unnecessary once the investigator connects the drive to trusted equipment.

Comment: Regarding encryption, you've described a bit of a catch-22.  We can't trust the live OS, but we need it for the keys.   Also, if we do anything short of powering the OS down, we compromise the disk.  The use for a write blocker would be if you could insert it between the suspect's hardware and the drive while the OS is still live.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog The point of a write blocker is to make it easy to prove that you didn't contaminate the evidence. For example, accidentally mounting a filesystem and modifying its journal is an easy mistake to make. Regarding encryption, there's no circularity: if you grab the key from the live system and then use it to decrypt the backup, it'll show that it's the right key. You aren't trusting the live OS.

Comment: yes, but as you pointed out, the live system may be programmed to destroy/modify sensitive data on the disk if it detects an attempt to retrieve the key.

Comment: It's all a question of what kind of suspect this is.  Maybe you can't trust the controller on the disk either.  At that point, you have to remove the physical storage media out and put it into a known environment to read it.  But of course most investigators can't do that on the premises.