# How to create a large file in UNIX?

Tags: shell, files

I found a way in Windows to do such thing

```
echo "This is just a sample line appended  to create a big file. " > dummy.txt
for /L %i in (1,1,21) do type dummy.txt >> dummy.txt
```

http://www.windows-commandline.com/how-to-create-large-dummy-file/

Is there a way in UNIX to copy a file, append and then repeat the process?
Something like `for .. cat file1.txt > file1.txt`?

Comment: Why copy the file and append instead of just appending ?

Comment: @123 append is good, but how to do the loop?

Comment: `for i in {1..1000000};do echo "string" >> file;done` in bash.

Comment: Does it have to be a text file? You can make any size of file from /dev/zero or /dev/urandom.

Comment: I'd expect `type file >> file` to run in an infinite loop (at least as soon as it's sufficiently large that it doesn't fit in a buffer).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What, why would that be an infinite loop? `type` is going to load the contents of `file` into memory, then open `file` for writing and append the loaded contents, then exit.

Comment: @tac, you mean if the file is 5TB large, type is going to load it whole in memory before display? After all it's Microsoft, why would I be surprised...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm pretty sure that `type` would just run out of memory, because NTFS and the NT kernel lock any file that's opened for reading / writing, unlike POSIX where there are no implicit locks.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm also pretty certain there aren't any `seek`-esque syscalls in NT, so you have no choice but to `malloc` the length of the file at once.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
yes "Some text" | head -n 100000 > large-file
```

With `csh`/`tcsh`:

```
repeat 10000 echo some test > large-file
```

With `zsh`:

```
{repeat 10000 echo some test} > large-file
```

On GNU systems, see also:

```
seq 100000 > large-file
```

Or:

```
truncate -s 10T large-file
```

(creates a 10TiB sparse file (very large but doesn't take any space on disk)) and the other alternatives discussed at ["Create a test file with lots of zero bytes"](/q/102613).

---

Doing `cat file >> file` would be a bad idea.

First, it doesn't work with some `cat` implementations that refuse to read files that are the same as their output file. But even if you work around it by doing `cat file | cat >> file`, if `file` is larger than `cat`'s internal buffer, that would cause `cat` to run in an infinite loop as it would end up reading the data that it has written earlier.

On file systems backed by a rotational hard drive, it would be pretty inefficient as well (after reaching a size greater than would possibly be cached in memory) as the drive would need to go back and forth between the location where to read the data, and that where to write it.

Comment: Or `dd if=/dev/zero of=large-file bs=1024 count=1024` for a 1MB file

Comment: @DougO'Neal I find `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=1` to be clearer.

Comment: @DougO'Neal, see [Create a test file with lots of zero bytes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102613)

Comment: Or use /dev/urandom instead of /dev/zero if you want random data.

Comment: I appreciate Stéphane's answers but I think of Doug's as the typical one.

Comment: @robertotomás, again, if it's to create a large file filled with zeroes, see [Create a test file with lots of zero bytes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102613) linked in the answer, where `dd if=/dev/zero` is the least efficient.

Comment: hi @StéphaneChazelas , I'm a little confused. Why did you write back to tell me that? The answer you've already written has several inefficient solutions at the top. I actually thought we were in agreement that efficiency doesnt matter for such small "large files". My comment was just pointing out that one of the answers in this discussion is in my opinion the typical _lazy_ solution.

Comment: @robertotomás, why would it be typical or lazy? It's longer to type than the truncate or fallocate or `dd seek=xxx` ones, so less lazy in terms of human effort and also a lot less lazy in terms of computer effort.

Comment: as you can see in the comment above, and other answers below, it is in fact a common answer. everyone _uses_ `dd`, and it is an important tool to know if you find yourself doing cli admin tasks. _/dev/zero_ might be relatively slow but you can always use a form like `yes|dd of=...` if you prefer. answers that do not use `dd` don't reinforce the memory of essential admin tools. — again, I want to reiterate, and this is visible in my initial comment, I don't think you are wrong, neither in your answers nor in the comment that `dd if=/dev/zero` can be slow. I was just talking about what is common

Comment: @robertotomás yes,  everyone uses `dd`, but I have never understood why.  In fact, I think I've only ever used it to read an MBR or similar fringe tasks.  In my experience, other tools are faster, simpler and safer for the vast majority of cases where people use `dd`.  I think this is one of those cases where common != optimal, like `sudo su` or `cat file | grep foo`.

Comment: @terdon the reason people use dd for disk images is because they've seen it used in tutorials and such and assume there's some reason behind it. The _original_ reason for using it was a bug in an early version of GNU cp (which could otherwise be used) that caused it to screw up in writing all-zero blocks. I've written about this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189091/6290

Comment: The proper non-dd way of doing this specific task would be `head -c 1048576 /dev/zero > file`

Comment: @terdon It's mostly fs-agnostic and always works. But it's more sane to use it when you really want to copy byte-by-byte Images (isol for example. It's fast if you give proper values for bs=

Answer (score 22):

You can create a large file on Solaris using:

```
mkfile 10g /path/to/file
```

Another way which works on Solaris (and Linux):

```
truncate -s 10g /path/to file
```

It is also possible to use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file bs=1048576 count=10240
```

Comment: dd one is like a terabyte

Comment: Define "a large file" :-) But I edited since the other samples all state 10g...

Comment: truncate 
Can't execute 'truncate'. No such file or directory
Truncate seems to be Linux only.

Comment: `truncate` does exist on Solaris 11.2+

Answer (score 14):

The fastest way possible to create a big file in a Linux system is `fallocate`:

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G bigfile
```

`fallocate` manipulates the files system, and does not actually writes to the data sectors by default, and as such is *extremely* fast. The downside it is that it has to be run as root.

Running it successively in a loop, you can fill the biggest of filesystems in a matter of seconds.

From `man fallocate`

> fallocate  is  used  to manipulate the allocated disk space for a
>   file,
>          either to deallocate or preallocate it.
>   For filesystems  which  support
>          the  fallocate system call, preallocation is done quickly by allocating
>          blocks and marking them as uninitialized, requiring no IO to  the  data
>          blocks.  This  is  much  faster than creating a file by filling it with
>          zeros.
>   Supported for XFS (since Linux 2.6.38), ext4 (since Linux  3.0),
>                 Btrfs (since Linux 3.7) and tmpfs (since Linux 3.5).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Easy and fast.

Answer (score 10):

This will keep going until you CTRL-C:

`yes This is stuff that I want to put into my file... >> dummy.txt`

Be  careful though, because you can get a hundreds of thousands of lines/second...

From `man yes`:

```
yes - output a string repeatedly until killed
```

Comment: This is a very easy method to create a big file in linux environment.

Comment: `yes $BIG_STRING | head -c $TARGET_SIZE >> dummy.txt` would let you get precise amount. (-n $TARGET_NUMBER_OF_LINES). `yes` would automatically die as result of a 'broken pipe' when `head` terminates because the target number has been reached.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like:

```
echo "test line" > file;
for i in {1..21}; do echo "test line" >> file; done
```

That will create a file with 22 repetitions of "test line". If you want a specific file size, you can use something like this (on Linux). 1024 is one kilobyte:

```
while [ $(stat -c "%s" file) -le 1024 ]; do echo "test line" >> file; done
```

Personally, when I want to create a large file, I use two files and cat one into the other. You can repeat the process until you reach the desired size (1MB here):

```
echo "test line" > file;
while [ $(stat -c "%s" file) -le 1048576 ]; do 
    cat file >> newfile
    cat newfile >> file
done
```

Note that this solution will often exceed the desired size because if the file is under the limit, everything will be catted into it again.

Finally, if all you want is a file of the desired size and don't need it to actually contain anything, you ca use `truncate`:

```
truncate -s 1M file
```

Comment: Does `cat`ing the file actually have any advantage to just appending though ? It would seem as though it would take longer as it has to fork two processes every loop and also move the entire contents multiple times.

Comment: @123 speed. The `cat` approach is much, much faster. It only makes sense for creating huge files but that created a 545M file in 10 seconds on my machine. The same `while` loop with `echo "test line" >> file` created a 96K file in the same amount of time.

Comment: I guess the thing with the "cat" approach is that it grows exponentially. On starting the second iteration, 'newfile' already has 1 line and 'file' has 2, and when it is done, 'newfile' is now 3 lines and 'file' is 5. Next, 'newfile' will be 8 and 'file' will be 13. Next (21, 34), etc.

Comment: downside: it may take more disk space (>= 1.5 * desired_size) than target file size while it is creating the file.

Comment: btw. If you have `truncate` around, you can `truncate -s 1G` to create the file in first place. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269184/85549. You could replace it by a `head -c $DESIRED_SIZE`, possibly within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 4):

By piping the contents of `/dev/urandom` to `head` you can redirect the output to a file, so :

```
 cat /dev/urandom | head --bytes=100 >> foo.bar
```

Will give you a file with 100 bytes of garbage.

Comment: Would /dev/zero be faster?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "This is just a sample line appended  to create a big file. " > dummy.txt
i=1
while [ $i -le 21 ]
do
  cat dummy.txt >> bigfile
  cat bigfile > dummy.txt
  (( i++ ))
done
```

same effect of your windows script but in bash, you can not concatenate a file to itself, directly.

Comment: Apart from forgetting the `.txt` extension, you're leaving 2 big files at the end.