# How can I get the size of stdin?

Tags: files, pipe, disk-usage, stdin, size

I'm about to compress a large directory and I want to know how large, exactly, the resulting file will be.

I've tried using `du`:

```
$ tar -cv dir | du -h -
du: cannot access '-': No such file or directory
```

Then I tried using the file version of '-':

```
$ tar -cv dir | du -h /dev/stdin
1.0K
```

I'm certain this number isn't accurate. How can I get the size of stdin?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `tar -cv dir | wc -c - | cut -d' ' -f 1 | awk '{print $1/1000"K"}'`

`du` doesn't actually count the size of the file itself. It just asks the kernel to query the filesystem, which already keeps track of file size. This is why it's so fast. Because of that, and the fact that you're counting a stream, not a file, `du` doesn't work. My guess is that `1.0K` is a hardcoded size for `/dev/std*` in the kernel.

The solution is to use `wc -c`, which counts bytes itself instead of querying the kernel:

```
$ tar -cv dir | wc -c
```

If you want output similar to `du -h`:

```
$ tar -cv dir | wc -c | awk '{print $1/1000"K"}'
```

The `awk` turns the number into a human-readable result.

Comment: Note that if you just omit `wc`'s superfluous `-` then you don't need the subsequent `cut` command either.

Comment: 1.0K is the block size of stdin.

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest:

```
tar cf - dir | wc -c
```

A simple `c` (no leading `-` is required) is used to create a `tar` archive, `f` specifies an output file and `-` denotes that it be *stdout*. (Note that if you want just the size and there are many files beneath *dir* you may rather omit `tar`'s `v` for performance reasons.)

Comment: @mikeserv; I seem to recall that I worked with `tar`s in the past where specifying a tar-file (thus `f` and `-`) were required. - Just looked it up; without `f` `-` the `tar` assumed `/etc/mt0` as default.

Comment: I've looked it up in a book that I used as a manual at that time, and *I think* was based on SysV R4. Few folks certainly recall what `/etc/mt0` actually means - "magnetic tape" ;-)  I'd be interested how Solaris' `tar` behaves (because Solaris is one of the contemporary OSes that are known to have still really old stuff in `/bin`).

Comment: @mikeserv; PS: The book mentions AT&T's *"UNIX Programmers Manual Volumes 1, 2A, 2B"* as source (but no manual date or UNIX release version, though; but must have been from the early 1980's, 1983, or so).

Comment: Have you ever seen [this](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/publications/prus-1995-1.pdf)? Unrelated - but I just found it today, and thought you might like it.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this answer is different from mine. is it the presence of the `-f` flag to `tar`?

Comment: @strugee; It was a bit more different before you edited yours just a few minutes ago. The current differences are, 1) unnecessary use of `v`, unnecessary use of `-` (in front of `c`, which is of course just a detail), possible problem with some versions of `tar` that expect `-f -` if *stdin* is concerned.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: Best answer, easy to remember!

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `tar` you can just do:

```
tar --totals -c . >/dev/null
```

...which will render output like...

```
Total bytes written: 5990400 (5.8MiB, 5.5GiB/s)
```

...on stderr. Similarly, with any tar *(or stream)* you can use `dd` to deliver a report on byte counts. This may or may not be preferable to `wc`, but `dd` defaults to a block-size of 512 bytes - which is identical to `tar`'s block-size. If your system's [*PIPE_BUF*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192114/52934) is large enough, you can even expand `dd`'s block-size to match `tar`'s record size - which is 20 blocks, or 10240 bytes. Like this:

```
tar -c . | dd bs=bx20 >/dev/null
585+0 records in
585+0 records out
5990400 bytes (6.0 MB) copied, 0.0085661 s, 699 MB/s
```

This may or may not offer a more performant solution than `wc`.

In both the `dd` and `tar` use-cases you needn't actually dispose of the stream, though. I redirect to `/dev/null` above - but I could have as easily redirected to some file and still received the report on its size at the time it was written.

Comment: In case the file gets written to disk there would be no use to separately determine the size since that information is stored with the file. (+1) for the expected performance gain of `dd` (compared to `wc`).

Comment: @Janis - possibly true in the simplest case - but imagine rather that `dd`'s output is passed on - to a compressor, say - and for whatever reason you find it desirable to know both the raw size of the archive and the compressed one. Also useful is to get an instant report on the record counts - `tar` is not just an archive, but a stream format. It can be used in ways other than just saving to a group of files to some other file. It is often useful for blocking a stream before modifying it. At each of those record boundaries is a whole block of NULs.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for [@strugee's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206734/) but I'll use the [numfmt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) tool which is designed for memory unit conversion and supports many options:

```
tar cf - dir | wc -c | numfmt --to=si
```

`--to=si` will display the output in SI units (e.g: 4M means 4000000 bytes). If you prefer so-called "binary" units, pass `--iec-i` (e.g: 4Mi means 4194304 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

The wording of your question lends itself to the `tar ... | wc -c` answers above. I originally read your question with a silent assumption that you wanted the size to be reported while it was creating the tar file (perhaps tar's output was then being piped over a network link?).

In which case, I'd suggest `pv` -- pipe viewer. I've seen reference to it but have not yet had a chance to play with it.

**References**

- http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/
- http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml