# Possible to pause dd, swap out destination to larger disk, and then continue?

Tags: hard-disk, dd

I'm copying a drive to a file, but underestimated the amount of space it would take up.  So I am running out of space on the destination drive, and don't want to abort the process (it's been running quite a while on a damaged drive).

I can of course pause dd using CTRL-Z, and I'd like to swap out the destination drive for a larger one and copy the file over to the larger drive, then resume dd.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
dd if=/dev/sdc conv=sync,noerror bs=64M | gzip -c -9 > /media/extD/drive.img.gz
```

EDIT:  for those mentioning ddrescue as being a better tool to use, you're right.  However, for whatever reason ddrescue kept barfing and erroring out on me, whilst dd has simply been chugging along without complaint.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to start dd again, if you can't free up enough space on destination drive. Next time don't piping to gzip, then you can continue dd from the last position to another destination.

Comment: If I kill dd but not gzip, can I then extract the dd img file and continue using that?  Also, you say without using dd I can continue from last position but don't give any details on the how?

Comment: dd skip=X seek=X ...
from manual:

       seek=N skip N obs-sized blocks at start of output


       skip=N skip N ibs-sized blocks at start of input

Comment: @IporSircer not really, see my answer. I've done exactly this on my laptop.

Comment: “it's been running quite a while on a damaged drive” I'd just start over with [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but kinda painful.

First, know that `dd` prints its current position in a copy (bytes copied) if sent the *USR1* signal. so find the *PID* of `dd`, using either `ps` or something like `pidof` or `pgrep` (not *POSIX* and not on all unix-y systems IIRC).

A `ps` command that works for me (also using `awk`, in a *debian* environment):

```
ps aux|awk '/dd/ {print $2}'|grep -v awk
```

`grep -v awk` is necessary to prevent the *PID* of `awk` from printing as well.

Having the *PID* of `dd`, send the *USR1* signal:

```
kill -USR1 [pid of dd]
```

the console window `dd` is running in will print how many bytes it's copied. You may now kill `dd` for real (ctrl+c, `kill -9`, whatever). I don't recall whether `dd` reports its progress on abort if killed this way in *POSIX*, so send the *USR1* signal first.

`dd` may have now copied a few more bytes since you stopped it, so run:

```
head -c [number of bytes reported copied from dd] > \
     /path/to/drive/you/are/moving/to/filename.bin
```

to put a truncated copy on the destination disk. Instead of the precise number of bytes, you may want to choose something divisible by your desired block size, to speed up the transfer when you resume the copy. Just make note of whatever you choose, and make sure you are only truncating, not growing, the image.

Once you have this copied to the new drive, run:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc bs=64M skip=[truncated size divided by block size, e.g. 64000000] \
   of=/path/to/part2
```

If you have space for the remainder of the image on the smaller original disk, delete the non-truncated image you copied to the new disk in *part 1* to free space, and have `dd` output it to that disk instead. When the transfer is complete, you can run

```
cat /path/to/part2 >> /path/to/part1
```

to add *part 2* to the end of *part 1*, creating a complete disk image! Note that you will need at least as much free space on the disk *part 1* is located on for all of part two to be appended to it.

If you don't mind doing the whole transfer over, I'd do `cat /dev/sdc | gzip -c - > /path/to/imagefile.img.gz` to create a gzip compressed archive. This can be written to a hard disk partition with something like `zcat /path/to/imagefile.img.gz > /dev/sdX`.

[copied from my comment into the answer]

additionally, I think (but do not remember for certain) that dd writes to stdout if of= is not specified. If this is true, you can skip writing part2 to a separate file and use:

```
dd bs=64M skip=[skip-block-count] if=/dev/sdc >> /path/to/part1
```

@MatijaNalis has rightly suggested using `dd_rescue` or `ddrescue` (two different programs that accomplish the same task) to copy the disk image. I'd do this if your partition/drive has erroneous sectors or other hardware faults.

Comment: additionally, I think (but do not remember for certain) that `dd` writes to stdout if `of=` is not specified. If this is true, you can skip writing part2 to a separate file and use `dd bs=64M skip=[skip-block-count] if=/dev/sdc >> /path/to/part1`.

Comment: Also, if you were to start transfer again, it would be much better to recover data from damaged disk by using https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ (or http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/ ) instead of `dd` if possible

Comment: That last do-over could be `gzip -c /dev/sdc > /path/to/imagefile.img.gz`

Comment: So that procedure will let gzip properly exit, so I can access the truncated file in the archive?

Comment: Counting the number of bytes that `dd` has copied is pointless. The useful information is the number of bytes that `gzip` has written, and you get that with `gzip -l`.

Comment: @MatijaNalis Good point.

Comment: @Giles if you aren't using gzip and are doing a raw disk copy, then the gzip advice won't help.

Comment: @Logos gzip when used on a file or pipe will stop at EOF (end of file). So yeah, should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pause the process and resume it after moving the file on another drive¹. However you don't need to do that. Just kill the `dd` process, do your file transfer, and initiate a new copy process for the rest of the data.

To see where the first part stops, run `gzip -l /media/extD/drive.img.gz`. The “uncompressed” number is the number of bytes that were copied, and it's the offset where you need to start the new copy process.

To copy the rest of the data, tell `dd` to start at that offset *NNNN*.

```
dd if=/dev/sdc conv=sync,noerror,iflag=skip_bytes,skip=NNNN bs=64M |
gzip -c -9 >> /media/extE/drive.img.gz
```

I do not recommend using `dd` to copy data. Contrary to a common legend, there is no magic in `dd` that lets it access disks: the magic is all in `/dev/sdc`. Furthermore [`dd` can lose data silently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) — I think that with the flags `conv=sync,noerror` it only replaces some data by zeros, so all the data that's successfully copied ends up at the right location, but do it at your own risk.

To copy a disk image from a working disk, just use `cp` or `cat`. To copy a part, `tail -c +$((start_offset+1)) | head -c $bytes_to_copy`.

To rescue data from a failing disk, use [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html). Ddrescue is smart about skipping unreadable data and keeps track of what it's successfully read. It makes multiple passes; with failing hard drives, letting the drive rest for a bit and trying again can often let you recover the whole thing, even if some sectors are unreadable at the first attempt.

[ddrescue can use your existing partial copy and complete it](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Generate-mode), but you'll have to keep it uncompressed.

¹  <sub>Actually, you can, with `ptrace` — attach to the process with a debugger, pause it, update its internal data structures to point to the new file, resume. But even if you were familiar with how to do that, it would be more complicated than the straightforward solution with appending.</sub>

Comment: This is good, and I agree on using `cat` instead, but if the disk is faulty `dd_rescue` is the way to go. And on certain types of (mostly extinct) hardware, block transfers are faster. Also I believe that besides the ddrescue bit, my answer covered all of this, didn't it? (i've since added the ddrescue bit)

Comment: Actually, did not know that two `gzip` streams appended together would decompress properly into one file.