# What file system type does a flash drive have after being `dd` an iso file into

Tags: filesystems, dd, iso

I am following this post to create bootable Ubuntu flash drive. https://askubuntu.com/a/377561

Suppose my flash drive is `/dev/sdb`.

After running

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

does the flash drive have a file system? If yes, what file system type?

Thanks.

Comment: last i heard it was a "squashfs".  ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS

Comment: `dd` does not create any filesystem by itself, but creates an exact copy of the input. So if your `.iso` file has e.g. ISO9660, then the flash drive will have the same. You can find out with `file input.iso` and `file /dev/sdb`.

Comment: do you mean `ISO9660` is a file system type? @ridgy

Comment: "ISO 9660 is the standard file system for CD-ROMs" (http://wiki.osdev.org/ISO_9660)

Answer (score 2):

`dd` just copies the input to the output. `dd bs=4M if=input.iso of=/dev/sdb` is equivalent to `cat input.iso >/dev/sdb` ([unless `dd` decides not to copy the whole input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial)). This command doesn't create a filesystem, it copies whatever the file `input.iso` contains.

If, as the name suggests, `input.iso` contains an [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) filesystem (the filesystem of CD-ROMs), then this is what the flash drive will contain. If `input.iso` contains something else then that something else is what the flash drive will contain.

Comment: Thanks. can an iso file contain a file system of any file system type, or contain data without file system at all? How can I find out the file system type contained in an iso file?

Comment: You might rename any file you like to `something.iso`. In *nix OS the file extension is just a convenience, but does not mean anything really. To find out the content of a file, use `file <filename>`, in your case `file input.iso`; this looks for the 'real' content of the file. See my older comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `dd` command just copies data from `input.iso` archive to `/dev/sdb`. File system is just a convention to organize data on a device/disk, and `dd` doesn't care about it.

And FYI, an iso archive contains `ISO9660` filesystem.