# What is the maximum value for the bs argument of dd?

Tags: dd

I want to write a CGI, which must read a specified number of bytes from STDIN. My idea is to do it this way:

```
dd bs=$CONTENT_LENGTH count=1
```

But I was wondering, if the block size is limited by anything else but the RAM.

```
$ dd bs=1000000000000
dd: memory exhausted by input buffer of size 1000000000000 bytes (931 GiB)
```

The manual page of GNU's coreutils does not specify any limit.

Comment: It depends on RAM and swap and GNU is irrelevant here.

Comment: "I want to write a CGI [in shell, using dd]" very bad idea. Also, no matter how big your `$CONTENT_LENGTH` is, that `dd` command may read just a single byte. If successful.

Comment: @mosvy `stat` can be used to check the size of a file.

Comment: How about writing it in perl instead?

Comment: there is no limit to bs

Comment: @JoelFan One limit is in my question and the other limits are in Stephen's answer, which he wrote yesterday.

Comment: @ceving perhaps JoelFan’s comment was a play on words...

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh sorry. My English is not good enough to understand it.

Comment: @ceving no need to apologise, I’m sure your English is better than my German! See [this wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BS#Verb) for a possible interpretation (used as a noun).

Comment: As an alterantive, fallocate doesn't require memory buffer to be allocated beforehand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[The POSIX specifications for `dd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) don’t specify a maximum explicitly, but there are some limits:

- the datatype used to store the value given can be expected to be [`size_t`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html), since that’s the type of the number of bytes to read given to [the `read` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html);
- `read` is also specified to have a limit of [`SSIZE_MAX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html);
- under Linux, [`read` only transfers up to 2,147,479,552 bytes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html#NOTES) anyway.

On a 64-bit platform, `size_t` is 64 bits in length; in addition, it’s unsigned, so `dd` will fail when given values greater than 2<sup>64</sup> – 1:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=18446744073709551616
dd: invalid number: ‘18446744073709551616’
```

On Linux on 64-bit x86, `SSIZE_MAX` is 0x7fffffffffffffffL (run `echo SSIZE_MAX | gcc -include limits.h -E -` to check), and that’s the input limit:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=9223372036854775808
dd: invalid number: ‘9223372036854775808’: Value too large for defined data type

$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=9223372036854775807
dd: memory exhausted by input buffer of size 9223372036854775807 bytes (8.0 EiB)
```

Once you find a value which is accepted, the next limit is the amount of memory which can be allocated, since `dd` needs to allocate a buffer before it can read into it.

Once you find a value which can be allocated, you’ll hit the `read` limit (on Linux and other systems with similar limits), [unless you use GNU `dd` and specify `iflag=fullblock`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17295/86440):

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=ddtest bs=4294967296 count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB, 2.0 GiB) copied, 38.3037 s, 56.1 MB/s
```

(`dd` copied just under 2<sup>31</sup> bytes, *i.e.* the Linux limit mentioned above, not even half of what I asked for).

As explained in the Q&A linked above, you’ll need `fullblock` to reliably copy all the input data in any case, for any value of `bs` greater than 1.

Comment: `2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB, 2.0 GiB) copied` That number is exactly as documented: *"On Linux, `write()` (and similar system calls) will transfer at most 0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes"*. See [cannot write(2) file larger than 2GB (up to 2TB)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44939835/995714)

Comment: Yes, see the third bullet point.

Comment: The "fullblock" problem gets triggered in a CGI almost always, because the CGI reads from a pipe as in the following example: `{ printf a; sleep 1; printf b; } | dd bs=2 count=1 2>/dev/null | wc -c`. In this example `dd` used without the fullblock option reads just one byte instead of two.

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of its maximum value, you have a bigger problem there; from the POSIX spec:

> The `dd` utility shall copy the specified input file to the specified output file with possible conversions using specific input and output block sizes. It shall read the input one block at a time, using the specified input block size; it shall then process the block of data actually returned, ***which could be smaller than the requested block size.***

(emphasis added)

[As I wrote in the past](https://twitter.com/cvtsi2sd/status/1189863959232466944), `dd` is an extremely stupid tool: in your case, it essentially boils down to

```
char *buf = malloc(bs);
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    int len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, bs);
    if(len == 0) break;
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, len);
}
free(buf);
```

`bs` is just the argument `dd` uses to perform the `read(2)` syscall, but `read(2)` is allowed to perform a "short read", i.e. to return less bytes than requested. Indeed, it's what it does if it has some bytes available right now, even if they aren't all you asked for; this is typical if the input file is a tty, a pipe or a socket (so you are particularly at risk with your CGI...). Just try:

```
$ dd bs=1000 count=1
asd
asd
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
4 bytes copied, 1.75356 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Here I typed in `asd` and pressed enter; `dd` read it (performing a single `read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1000)` and wrote it out; it did one `read` as requested, so it exits. It doesn't look like it copied 1000 bytes.

Ultimately, plain "standard" `dd` is a way too stupid tool for most needs; you can wrangle it to do what you need by either:

- by using `bs=1` and using `count` for the number of bytes; this is guaranteed to copy the number of bytes you need (if available before EOF), but it's quite inefficient, as it performs one syscall per byte;
- add the `fullblock` flag; this makes sure that `dd` accumulates a full input block before writing it out. Notice however that this is nonstandard (GNU dd has it, IDK about others).

Ultimately, if you are going for non-POSIX extension, my suggestion is to just use `head -c`: it will do the Right Thing with sensible buffering and no particular size limits, ensuring correctness and good performance.

Comment: It requires 5 lines of shell code to check the size of a file. It is ok for me to buffer in memory. My upload limit is 100 MB.

Comment: @ceving: ... and what do you gain? more complicated code that is just as brittle as the original? Just use `head -c`, it's concise and works correctly in all the cases.

Comment: Yes, it's the most important point here. You'd only use `dd` if you wanted to make sure the data is read in one `read()` system call which in the OP's *CGI* context doesn't make much sense. Might be worth pointing out that CGIs should never be written as shell scripts if they take any input from the client as it's very difficult to avoid vulnerabilities there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know many vulnerabilities in various web toolkits. But what can go wrong, when I write stdin with `dd` into a file? I would say this is the most secure way to handle uploads.

Comment: @ceving, if it's just `head -c 100M > /fixed/path/to/file` it's fine (as long as the shell is not a version of bash vulnerable to shellshock), but if the rest of the script handles any CGI input (CGI parameters, REQUEST_URI, HTTP_HOST...), then you're probably in big trouble already. Over half the CGI shell scripts I've seen had vulnerabilities in them.

Comment: @ceving: IDK why are you so set with using `dd` - it will use a huge buffer for no reason and, most importantly, it _won't do the right thing_ if the input comes from a socket, which is the norm when writing a CGI. I said it in the answer, but let me say it again: a `dd` with `count=1` and a "big" block size will stop at whatever quantity of data is available in the socket right now, generally way earlier than your set block size.

Comment: (also, of course I agree with @StéphaneChazelas, never saw a safe CGI written in shell)

Comment: @MatteoItalia If its done, I will put it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: _"But what can go wrong, when I write stdin with dd into a file? I would say this is the most secure way to handle uploads."_ - Shell is notoriously dangerous for things like this; it can often be influenced by out-of-band options, such as environment variables. Although this was a specific incident, [Shellshock](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68122/what-is-a-specific-example-of-how-the-shellshock-bash-bug-could-be-exploited) is a good example that reminded the world of this.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum depends on the system (including its allocation policies) and the currently available memory.

Instead of trying to read everything at once (you could exhaust memory, slow things down because of swap, you would have to add checks to see if it actually worked ...) you could read reasonable sized blocks with `dd`.

Let's say you want to read those bytes and put them into a file. In bash you could run something like this (the total bytes are in $total):

```
block=65535
count=$(expr $total / $block)
rest=$(expr $total % $block)
(dd bs=$block count=$count;dd bs=$rest count=1) > filename
```