# dd command ruining files

Tags: raspbian, dd, corruption

I recently was trying to flash from an IMG file with `dd`, and it took a lot shorter than normal, and when I checked the drive, it had names like

```
\u2584\u00bc\u2591+\u03c6\u256bv\u2559.|
```

I don't know if I'm being stupid, or if it's a drive error. This is the code I used:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/tails-amd64-4.20.img of=/dev/sdd1 bs=1M
```

Comment: `\u2584` is unicode for a bottom half block.  `\u00bc` is unicode for `1/4`.  This looks like an encoding issue.  Did you intend for this image to have unicode-characters in the filenames?

Comment: Is the image itself sound?  `file` should be able to tell you what it thinks (e.g. if it's a compressed file rather than an actual image, for example) and `fsck -n` can check it, I think.  And you should be able to loopback-mount the file and inspect it.  If those succeed, then start to look at the copy command (probably worth issuing a `sync` before using it, too).

Comment: I think [`bs` without `count` is safe with a modern `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial), but just in case, try using `cat` instead. Of course, check that the image is good — `sudo mount -o loop ~/Downloads/tails-amd64-4.20.img /mnt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Toby, I had switched up two files when downloading multiple files, so I accidentally renamed a zip into it. Thanks!

Yeah, I was just being stupid.