# dd: when is mandatory use bs and count together?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, dd, disk, io

I am reading many tutorials about the `dd` command. There are some examples including the `bs` and `count` parameters. Some of them where each one is isolated over the other and other where both are used together, but is not very clear the explicit relation about their values.

At a first glance seems enough and straight use only `bs` - and of course taking in consideration that `count` by default works with 512 bytes, it because `bs` by default is **512** bytes. It such as: `bs=512 count=#`.

**Question #1:**

- When and why is mandatory use both together?

According with some research, a `block` has a size of `512` bytes. For example - not sure if are valid:

```
bs=1M   count=10
bs=1M   count=5
bs=1.5M count=7
```

**Extra Question #2**

- Is there an explicit relation and rate for the values used for them together?

It for example to know if - `bs=1M count=10` - `bs=1M count=5` - `bs=1.5M count=7` - each one are correct or not - and **why**.

**Note:** I am assuming there is a kind of rate or rule to define the values when they are used together and therefore avoid to put any random value to see what happens - and harm the disk for a failed experiment. Correct if I am wrong.

**Reason:** because the `dd` command must be use it very carefully I want have very clear the use of them, isolated and together. Of course with the correct values. It is the reason to create this question.

**Goal** until now it is mentioned in many tutorials about to create a `swap file` - in my case for `Ubuntu`. How was not clear the `dd` syntax, I did do a research of this command and knew the other features, `convert` and `copy`

Comment: As a general advice about using the `bs` and `count` operands (together), make sure you understand the pitfalls: [When is dd suitable for copying data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17295/315749)

Comment: @fra-san thanks for the link, I am learning well `dd` to apply `swap file` in `Ubuntu`, but because it has other features, I am doing the research of this command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When and why is mandatory use both together?

It's important to know what your goal is. Without supplying `count`, `dd` will copy until EOF is reached (which for some block devices, like `/dev/zero`, will never be the case).

Otherwise, `dd` will copy `count` blocks of size `bs`.

> Is there an explicit relation and rate for the values used for them together?

This once again depends on your task. It can be beneficial to tune `bs` for speed, and `count` can be used to only copy a part of something.

To make things maybe a bit more clear, the following examples will all write a 1024 byte file.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/testfile count=2
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/testfile bs=1k count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/testfile bs=128 count=8
```

For more information, see the coreutils manual entries regarding [block size](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html) and [`dd` invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html#dd-invocation)

Comment: Thanks Panki -  added the `Goal` section just in case

Comment: The block example is valuable now I can see clearly the relation and kind of dependency between them, each other complements to indicate how do the copy process